# How are these two terms approximately equal?

Tags: calculus

How are these two terms approximately equal?
$$
{f'(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)f''(x_0)}\approx{f'(x_0+\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0))}
$$

Comment: Taylor approximation for $f'$.

Comment: You are probably familiar with $g(x_0+h)\approx g(x_0)+hg'(x_0)$. Let $g(x)=f'(x)$ and $h=\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, André Nicolas and Daniel Fischer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably familiar with the *tangent line approximation* or *linear approximation* formula
$$g(x_0+h)\approx g(x_0)+hg'(x_0),\tag{1}$$
which holds if $|h|$ is "small." The formula (1) is a consequence of the definition of $g'(x_0)$ as 
$$g'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(x_0+h)-g(x_0)}{h}.$$

For our particular example, let $g(x)=f'(x)$ and let $h=\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)$. If $|h|$ is small, then by Formula (1) we have
$$f'\left(x_0+\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)\right)\approx f'(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)f''(x_0).$$
This is the required approximation.